# How to convert below example into implements Runnable interface and override run method

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance

I have 2 simple classes like bellow. However i would like to implement the runnable interface in the class declaration instead of using it on Thread object declaration . However i am failing to gasp how to convert this into a above format.

```
public class Main{

    static Runner r1 =new Runner();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Thread t1 = new Thread (new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    r1.firstThread();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread (new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    r1.secondThread();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}


public class Runner {
    public void firstThread() throws InterruptedException
    {
    }

    public void secondThread() throws InterruptedException
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `class FooRunnable implements Runnable { @Override public void run() { ...} }; ...  new Thread(new FooRunnable());`

Comment: yes but this is 2 methods run in the same time in 2 different threads. so i am getting confused a bit

Comment: If you want that some class implement an interface like *Runnable* you just have to add the *implements* keyword followed by the interface name like Adrian Shum already show you, and then you need to implement the interface methods. Your class could contain whatever attributes or methods you need, this is not a problem.

Comment: @Optimuskck I don't know your specific case, but another way is to directly extend the Thread class.

Comment: Think "Runnable" as an "Action".  Given you have 2 actions (calling `runner.firstThread()` and `runner.secondThread()`), you can create two class for these two actions, and pass instance of each of them to a thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already passing an object implementing `Runnable`, though it is an anonymous class.

Nothing will stop you from pulling that out into a "named" class, e.g.

```
public class RunnerFirstAction implements Runnable {
    private Runner runner;
    public RunnerFirstAction(Runner runner) {
        this.runner = runner;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runner.first();
    }
}

public class RunnerSecondAction implements Runnable {
    private Runner runner;
    public RunnerSecondAction(Runner runner) {
        this.runner = runner;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runner.second();
    }
}


public class Main{

    static Runner r1 =new Runner();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread (new RunnerFirstAction(runner));
        Thread t2 = new Thread (new RunnerSecondAction(runner));
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .I got your idea. But that means i have to create 3 classes

Comment: Then tell me what do you mean by : "*...like to implement the runnable interface in the class declaration instead..*". You want to have class declaration (as said in quoted comment) but you don't want to have class declaration (as your comment in this answer)?

Comment: I do want to have it in class declaration . But cant we have only 2 classes? that is where i was confused

Comment: you can do anything in that `Runnable` class, there are a lot of way to do, you can pass an extra parameter in its ctor to decide which method to call, you can make use of lambda, you can pass the `Method` you get by reflection etc, it is your own choice.  But, what exactly is your problem? Can't you tell us clearly what you are trying to solve in real? It sounds an X-Y problem to me

Comment: Never mind i am just studying . Thanks for the answer .with your comment and with your answer i was able to understand it :)